# Sort algorithm in js with two conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a question - I'm working over a task. The task is to use sort() in js to divide array into two sections - firstly I have to show all numbers in array not divided by 3 descending and then all numbers divided by 3 ascending. I used random() to generate array of 100 random numbers (in case of examlpes - 20). Then i'm using a code to set numbers accordingly to thier divisibility.

Example

> 12, 75, 80, 47, 66, 60, 2, 65, 65, 68, 97, 32, 5, 14, 15, 11, 65, 53, 76, 97

```
    table.sort(
      function(a,b){
        if((a % 3) == 0)
        {
          return 1;
        }
        else if(a == 0)
        {
          return 0;
        }
        else
        {
          return -1;
        }
      }
    );
```

This works great.

> 80, 47, 2, 65, 65, 68, 97, 32, 5, 14, 11, 65, 53, 76, 97, 15, 60, 66, 75, 12

Now i have the same array where first numbers are not divided by 3, then vice versa. When I try to set values ascending and descending I have a few problems.

```
    table.sort(
      function(a,b){
        if((a % 3) == 0)
        {
          return a - b;
        }
        else if((a % 3) != 0)
        {
          return b - a;
        }
        else
        {
          return a;
        }
      }
    );
```

> 97, 97, 80, 76, 68, 65, 65, 65, 53, 47, 32, 15, 60, 66, 75, 14, 12, 11, 5, 2

First - it doesn't work for numbers belowe 11, just print it all descending regardless of their divisibility.
Secondly - it works good(ish) for numbers from 12 to around 100 - it does what it suppose to do but there is almost always (2 out of 3 times) some unsorted garbage (or sorted bad) on the back of the array.(Check exmalpe)
Thirdly - if values are set between 1000 and 10000 - it works great (I made few tests, maybe it fails but I didn't notice)

So here is the question - is there a way and how to repair my code so it will sort numbers in the same array as follow:

- not divided by 3, descending, first on array
- divided by 3, ascending, when all above are sorted

Thanks for any tips

@edit:

Snippet, as suggested:

```js
  var max = 100;

    table = [];

    for(var i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++)
    {
      var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
      table[i] = x;
    }
      console.log(table.join(", "));

    table.sort(
      function(a,b){
        if((a % 3) === 0)
        {
          return 1;
        }
        else if(a === 0)
        {
          return 0;
        }
        else
        {
          return -1;
        }
      }
    );
      console.log(table.join(", "));

    table.sort(
      function(a,b){
        if((a % 3) == 0)
        {
          return a - b;
        }
        else if((a % 3) !== 0)
        {
          return b - a;
        }
        else
        {
          return a;
        }
      }
    );
      console.log(table.join(", "));
```

Comment: A note on your use of JS comparators: never use `==` unless you know _exactly_ how type coercion works, and can explain why it's critical that JS should resort to it. Get in the habit of only ever using `===` and `!==`. With that said: if you have examples, turn your code into runnable snippets so folks can not just run them, but can also one-click-copy them into their answer to show you the fixed code.

Comment: Link to snippet: https://tech.io/snippet/PEkZQmB I'm curious - after you run the code it behave almost tottaly different to my firefox results... I'm getting confused even more

Comment: No. here. SO posts _come with snippet functionality_ so that you can put your [mcve] straight into your question (if it's an html/css/js question, which this is). Hit "edit", and then look for the little document icon with `<>`.

Comment: is it good now?

Answer (score 0):

```
let notDividedBy3 = table.filter(x => x % 3 !== 0).sort((a, b) => b - a);
let dividedBy3 = table.filter(x => x % 3 === 0).sort();
let result = [...notDividedBy3, ...dividedBy3];
console.log(result.join(", "));
```